# Change Spinner Triangle background color

Tags: android, mobile, spinner

I want to make spinner with the color of the triangle background, which is blue. But the basic color of spinner still same as before.

I only have found solutions  to change the triangle color or the basic color of spinner.

[See this](https://www.fluidui.com/editor/live/preview/p_BAuy2T4XohWwbPlqcr9ot2MsyZQsgaeu.1449121011087)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we have a snippet with some CSS and HTML showing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> **First Way (Simpler):**

In your xml, make sure your spinner has an id. In this example, let's call the id "spinner".

In your code, add the following in your onCreate():

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

where red is your defined color in your **colors.xml** in the values folder.

***or***

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#AA7744"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

> **Second Way:**

You can use this online tool: http://android-holo-colors.com

It is really great. It will generate custom drawables for you with your preferred color. Make sure you choose the theme as holo (or anything else you want) and select spinner.

> **Third Way:**

You should create a new 9 patch drawable and set it as a background to android:actionDropDownStyle.

here is an example:

```
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/customActionBarDropDownStyle</item>
    <style name="customActionBarDropDownStyle"parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_spinner_dropdown</item>
    </style>
```

You can't set a color to almost every native component, as their backgrounds are (in most cases) 9-patch pngs.

Comment: mention not @marcellojudhandoyo

Comment: What is **custom_spinner_dropdown**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it is only the background for dropdown of the spinner

Answer (score 0):

It became much simpler for API 21+:

```
 <Spinner
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
```